# C++ fstream writes garbage to file

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

The code below creates a vector that contains a vector of `char`s. It opens a `fstream` to a file. and then write the first `char` from the first vector. I tried to methods to write the char. Finally, I tried open a new 'fstream' and from it to print what I wrote. Both the printing and a simple inspection of the file shows it contian nothing, or sometimes garbage (dependening on the order of the `write`s). No errors or any weried output appear. I'm really loosing my mind over this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> y(6, 0);
    y[0] = 1;
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> vy;
    vy.push_back(y);
    std::fstream dateir("ffff.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    dateir<<vy[0][0] << endl;
    int temp = vy[0][0];
    dateir.write((char *)&temp, sizeof(int));
    dateir.close();

      cout << "here" << endl;
    std::ifstream dateir2("ffff.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    
    if (dateir2.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << dateir2.rdbuf();
      }
    else{
        cout << "no";
    }
    dateir2.close();
    cout << "end";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to find out where the garbage data was written?

Comment: `dateir.write((char *)&temp, sizeof(int));` writes binary data, it won't be human readable or printable as text. The data in the vector is also not a printable character.

Comment: @RetiredNinja The data I wish to write is wither binary. I only lookd at the file for debugging purposes (I also used the `txt` suffix for that case). About the printable characters - I took the vector definitions from a code that works fine like this (and the bug appeard whene I tried to change the writing command).

Comment: Sounds like not knowing how to use your debugger is getting you into trouble. Maybe it’s time to learn?

Comment: As I said, none of the data you're writing to the file, with the exception of the newline, is printable, so `std::cout << dateir2.rdbuf();` printing "garbage" is completely expected. If you look at the file with a hex editor you'll see that. https://godbolt.org/z/1fhdnzsxr

Comment: @Sneftel sounds like you are a bit rude.

Comment: Feel free to not take my advice, then. I can’t force you to learn stuff.

Comment: @RetiredNinja what do you mean by "not printable"? There is nothing wrong with writing someting like `cout << 6 << endl;`?

Answer (score 2):

You have...a number of problems here.

```cpp
std::fstream dateir("ffff.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
```

Is there a reason you've specified `std::ios::out | std::ios::out`? It's harmless, but clearly redundant.

As a first stab at things, I'd simplify the code a bit:

```cpp
std::ofstream out("ffff.dat", std::ios::binary);
int data = 1;
out.write((char *)&data, sizeof(data));
out.close();

std::ifstream in("ffff.dat", std::ios::binary);
int data2;
in.read((char *)&data2, sizeof(data2));

if (data == data2) {
    // what we read matched what we wrote
} else {
    // what we read didn't match what we wrote
}
```

When you write binary data to a file, you usually want to just read it back in the way you wrote it out. If you want to look at the individual characters, you can do that but to get something that's semi-readable, you probably want to print them out in hexadecimal, or something on that order (and for this sort of exercise to mean much, you'd probably want to print it out in hex both before writing it out, and after reading it back in, to show they match, and let the reader see a reasonable understandable representation of the file contents).